# Java OffsetDateTime.parse() adds extra zeros to time

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter, offsetdatetime

This following codes return an OffsetDateTime like this 2021-06-30T23:59:59.009966667Z, with 2 extra zeros added. I have 7 n's in the formatter, but it still returns 9 digits. Why?

```java
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         DateTimeFormatter MAIN_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnn XXX");
         String dbData = "2021-06-30 23:59:59.9966667 +00:00";
         OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.parse(dbData, MAIN_FORMATTER);
         System.out.println(time.toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was poorly formatted.

Comment: I swapped the n's with S's. and it worked!!!

Comment: Post and accept your own Answer so this page is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This following codes return an OffsetDateTime like this
> 2021-06-30T23:59:59.009966667Z, with 2 extra zeros added. I have 7 n's
> in the formatter, but it still returns 9 digits. Why?

You will get the same result even for a single `n` or any number of `n`s less than or equal to `7`. However, if you exceed `7`, you will get an exception something like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
               Text '2021-06-30 23:59:59.9966667 +00:00' could not be parsed at index 20
```

The reason for this is `DateTimeFormatter` counts the number of `n` in the pattern and if it is less than or equal to the number of digits after `.`, it will use additional `n` to compensate that but if the number of `n`s exceed the number of digits, it won't have any clue what that additional `n`s are for.

It's not just for `n` but for most (if not all) of the symbols. You can understand it from the following example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate1 = "2020/2/2";
        String strDate2 = "2020/02/02";

        // Notice the single M and d
        DateTimeFormatter dtfCorrectForBothDateStrings = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/M/d", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(strDate2, dtfCorrectForBothDateStrings));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(strDate1, dtfCorrectForBothDateStrings));

        // Notice the two M's and d's
        DateTimeFormatter dtfCorrectOnlyForSecondDateString = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(strDate2, dtfCorrectOnlyForSecondDateString));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(strDate1, dtfCorrectOnlyForSecondDateString));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02-02
2020-02-02
2020-02-02
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020/2/2' could not be parsed at index 5
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

### Why does it give me `.009966667` and not `.9966667`?

The symbol, `n` stands for *nano-of-second* and `9966667` nanoseconds are equal to `0.009966667` second.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nanos = 9966667;
        System.out.println(nanos + " nanoseconds = " + ((double) nanos / 1_000_000_000) + " second");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9966667 nanoseconds = 0.009966667 second
```

### How does it work with `S`?

`S` stands for *fraction-of-second* and `.9966667` is parsed as `0.9966667` second.

### A note on `OffsetDateTime#toString` implementation:

The `OffsetDateTime#toString` groups the digits of *fraction-of-second* in the nearest multiple of `3` (i.e. milli, micro and nano) e.g.

- for `.99`, the output will be `.990`, and
- for `.996`, the output will be `.996`, and
- for `.9966`, the output will be `.996600`, and
- for `.9966667`, the output will be`.996666700`.

Given below is an excerpt from `OffsetDateTime#toString`:

> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXXXX
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXXX
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSXXXXX

The final demo (incorporating all that have been discussed above):

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021-06-30 23:59:59.9966667 +00:00";

        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnn XXX", Locale.ENGLISH)));

        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS XXX", Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-30T23:59:59.009966667Z
2021-06-30T23:59:59.996666700Z
```